# how to unwind javascript object into Json object without duplicate entries

Tags: javascript

`existingJsObj = {"a": [1,2,3,4], "b":[11,22,33,44]}`

I want to convert this javascript into something that doesnt have array items in it, like below

`desiredJsObj = [{"a":1, "b":11},{"a":2,"b":22},{"a":3, "b":33},{"a":4, "b":44}]`

Comment: And the question is? It seems any regular coding problem

Comment: Show us what you have tried that isn't working. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: Are you saying that you want to convert an array of keys and an array of pairs into an array of key-value pairs?

Comment: create a js class like someObjectName{ a : 0, b : 0}; then create an array and fill it with instance of the "someObjectName" with it member filled by the values in array "a" and array "b"

Answer (score 1):

I would do following:

```
const income = {"a": [1,2,3,4], "b":[11,22,33,44]};

const res = income.a.map((a, i) => ({ a: a, b: income.b[i] }));
```

This works in assumption that "a" length is equal to "b" length.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the keys and the values while using a new array and object for the result.

```js
var object = { a: [1, 2, 3, 4], b: [11, 22, 33, 44] },
    array = Object.keys(object).reduce(function (r, k) {
        object[k].forEach(function (v, i) {
            (r[i] = r[i] || {})[k] = v;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
existingJsObj = {"a": [1,2,3,4], "b":[11,22,33,44]}
desiredJsObj = []
keys = Object.keys(existingJsObj);
existingJsObj[keys[0]].forEach((val, index) => {
    value = {};
    keys.forEach((key, i) => value[key] = existingJsObj[key][index])
    desiredJsObj.push(value)
})
```